# How do I post an Image object with a multi-part POST with Request?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to convert some `javascript` code I wrote to `Python`, but am getting stuck on passing data b/t `PIL` and `Requests` objects.

My `python` script downloads an image to memory:

```
from PIL import Image
import urllib2
import cStringIO

def fetch_image_to_memory(url):
   req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={
                         'User-Agent': "Mozilla / 5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko / 20071127 Firefox / 2.0.0.11"})
   con = urllib2.urlopen(req)
   imgData = con.read()
   return Image.open(cStringIO.StringIO(imgData))
```

I'd then like to add it to the `form data` for a `POST` operation.  This code succeeds when the file is on disk:

```
from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder
import requests
url = 'https://us-west-2.api.scaphold.io/graphql/some-gql-endpoint'

multipart_data = MultipartEncoder(
    fields={
         'query':'some-graphql-specific-query-string',
        'variables': '{ "input": {"blobFieldName": "myBlobField" }}',

        ## `variables.input.blobFieldName` must hold name 
        ## of Form field w/ the file to be uploaded
        'type': 'application/json',
        'myBlobField': ('example.jpg', img, 'image/jpeg')
    }
)
req_headers = {'Content-Type':multipart_data.content_type, 
             'Authorization':'Bearer secret-bearer-token'}
r = requests.post(url, data=multipart_data, headers=req_headers)
```

However, when trying to pass in an `Image` object from the `fetch_image_to_memory` function:

```
 'myBlobField': ('example.jpg', image_object, 'image/jpeg')
```

...I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-gql.py", line 38, in <module>
    'myBlobField': img
  File "/home/bmp/code/wayhome/python-phash/requests_toolbelt/multipart/encoder.py", line 119, in __init__
    self._prepare_parts()
  File "/home/bmp/code/wayhome/python-phash/requests_toolbelt/multipart/encoder.py", line 240, in _prepare_
parts
    self.parts = [Part.from_field(f, enc) for f in self._iter_fields()]
  File "/home/bmp/code/wayhome/python-phash/requests_toolbelt/multipart/encoder.py", line 488, in from_fiel
d
    body = coerce_data(field.data, encoding)
  File "/home/bmp/code/wayhome/python-phash/requests_toolbelt/multipart/encoder.py", line 466, in coerce_da
ta
    return CustomBytesIO(data, encoding)
  File "/home/bmp/code/wayhome/python-phash/requests_toolbelt/multipart/encoder.py", line 529, in __init__
    buffer = encode_with(buffer, encoding)
  File "/home/bmp/code/wayhome/python-phash/requests_toolbelt/multipart/encoder.py", line 410, in encode_wi
th
    return string.encode(encoding)
AttributeError: 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

I know from the [`open()` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) that it returns an object of type `file`, but the only way I can see in `PIL` to convert from `Image` to `file` is by using `save()`, which writes it to the disk.  I *can* write to disk, but I'd rather avoid the step, since I am handling a lot of images.

Is it possible to convert the `Image` object to `file` type? Or some other workaround with similar effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MultipartEncoder` can take a byte string or a file object, but a `PIL` image object is neither.

You'd have to create an in-memory file object first:

```
from io import BytesIO

image_file = BytesIO()
img.save(image_file, "JPEG")
image_file.seek(0)
```

then use *`image_file`* in the post:

```
'myBlobField': ('example.jpg', image_file, 'image/jpeg')
```

Comment: thanks Martijn. Do you know off the top of your head if this technique is meaningfully faster/slower than just writing the file to disk and using `open()`? Also: I think the second line should be `image_file = BytesIO()` , no?

Comment: @Brandon: yes, sorry about the typo. An in-memory file is going to be faster than writing this to disk. You have the memory already, you read the data into memory before in `fetch_image_to_memory()`.